# Trying to move files with with a specific format

Tags: vb.net

So what i am trying to do is move my files that have a .mp3 format from my downloads folder to my music folder. This is my current code:

```
Private Sub BtnMove_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnMove.Click
    Dim di As New DirectoryInfo("D:\Downloads")
    Dim files() As FileInfo = di.GetFiles("*.mp3", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

    My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile("D:\Downloads" + files(),
    "D:\Desktop\Music\")
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the **question**?

Comment: you need to iterate the array of files.  Object Browser, Intellisence and MSDN will all show you that `MoveFiles` takes a string, not string array

Comment: Im am that annoyed that people minus the question when it is a perfectly good question...

Comment: They probably downvoted it because the answer is actually so simple and because you don't seem to know how to handle arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're trying to move a file called "DownloadsSystem.IO.FileInfo[]" from the "D:\" drive, and you're trying to move it as a directory to "D:\Desktop\".

Here's what's wrong:

First, the `files()` array is a whole list filled with the object System.IO.FileInfo. You cannot use all objects in it at once on a single line. And since it is no string it will use the object's name instead when the application concatenates the two "strings"...

Secondly, if you look at the little box that pops up when you are typing the code `My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile(`, you will see that the arguments are source**FileName** and destination**FileName**. Which means that you gotta define **the name of the (wanted) file** in both arguments.

With that said, here's a code that will work:

```
Dim di As New DirectoryInfo("D:\Downloads")
Dim files() As FileInfo = di.GetFiles("*.mp3", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

For Each f As FileInfo In files
    My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile(f.FullName, Path.Combine("D:\Desktop\Music", f.Name))
Next
```